# evaluating dual blocking commands in a bash condition statement

Tags: bash, shell-script, read, inotify

I am attempting to write a loop that refreshes a terminal either

1. when the file(s) have been modified, or
2. when user input is detected second interval.

I know how to do one at a time, like so:

```
while inotifywait -q -e modify /path/to/file -r ; do ls; done
```

... and I can easily do

```
while read; do ls; ls; done
```

But how would I do them congruently? as in, refresh when either read returns true and/or when `inotifywait` returns true? I've tried a few examples, but I haven't put too much thought into it.

Comment: A silly brute force solution would be to poll them alternatively, with a short timeout. Unless you can get a single process to select() on both the inotify and terminal file handles, that might even be the only option...

Comment: how about toggle variable(s) that both commands modify? I would have to generate different loops for both commands and my subsequent command....

Answer (score 1):

You can always have two loops running in parallel:

```
while inotifywait -q -e modify /path/to/file -r; do ls; done &
  while read -r; do ls; done
wait
```

Comment: Simple and tasty.